# Last Observation on XTS Plot

Tags: r, plot, xts

Is there a way to add the value of the right most observation on an XTS plot? Another word, I want to display the most recent observation on the chart somehow.

Preferably a number on the axis? or Maybe a horizontal level line.

Comment: Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly.

Comment: To display the number, you can use `text`, for a horizontal line, `abline`. Do you have troubles figuring out the right coordinates to pass to these functions? Then please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You could show the latest value in the title of the plot (top left corner), and then mark a line on the xts chart for it:

```
# If you don't already have it, use latest version of xts for nicer plot.xts, which this code uses:
# devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")
# Sample data:
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("AAPL")
data <- AAPL["2016"]

# Solve the question:
lastval <- last(Cl(data))
plot(Cl(data), main = paste("latest value = ", round(lastval, 2)))
lines(xts(rep(lastval, NROW(data)), index(data)), on = 1, col = "red", lty = 2, main = "hi")

# Check we are we plotting the xts last value? (right most value)
> last(Cl(data))
AAPL.Close
2016-10-07     114.06
```

[image]

Quick and dirty approach: Are you aware that you could plot with package `quantmod`, and by default  they show the latest values "out of the box", which might be quicker/easier for you?  Use functions `chartSeries` and you could use `addTA`.  They show the latest values in the top left corners of the charts. For example:

```
chartSeries(Cl(AAPL["2016"]))
addTA(RSI(Cl(AAPL["2016"])))
```

[image]